# Which is faster: MySQL/PHP or serving straight from static files?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on very big project - quiz system (examination). And have a few questions about it. First of all,which is the best solution:

1) Getting all pages contents from MySQL database and creating php cache

or

2) Saving page contents in static files?

Which solution will work faster that other one?

Comment: Faster? Not much difference in speed. If you want to be able to easily modify the quizzes, or want to calculate results, use PHP/MySQL.

Comment: of course the page will get question from db tables. i'm talkin about all pages of the stie including landing page and etc.

Comment: I think saving everything in database will be the best choice...That is why the MySql made for..!!

Comment: is it safe? i mean data loss and something like that. can i create static (portable) db?

Comment: You can lose the database files about as easy as you could lose the static files. As for data corruption ... well, it's not common. It's highly unlikely if you don't go out of your way to power the server down in the middle of heavy operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Baseline-html

[Baseline-html is always faster than PHP because PHP needs to be invoked](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/1656).

```
The results follow (all are at 10 concurrent users, averaged over 5 one-minute runs):

ab                       |      rel |      avg |
------------------------ | -------- | -------- |
baseline-html            |   1.2660 |  3581.54 |
baseline-php             |   1.0000 |  2829.11 |

http_load                |      rel |      avg |
------------------------ | -------- | -------- |
baseline-html            |   1.2718 |  4036.24 |
baseline-php             |   1.0000 |  3173.56 |

siege                    |      rel |      avg |
------------------------ | -------- | -------- |
baseline-html            |   1.2139 |  5060.25 |
baseline-php             |   1.0000 |  4168.76 |
```

But luckily PHP is pretty fast and almost does not have any performance impact when you write optimized PHP code. PHP is a dynamic language so less is more.

### APC

Furthermore if you plan on working on a big site the first thing you should install is [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php). From the [WIKI page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator):

> Most PHP accelerators work by caching the compiled bytecode of PHP
>   scripts to avoid the overhead of parsing and compiling source code on
>   each request (some or all of which may never even be executed). To
>   further improve performance, the cached code is stored in shared
>   memory and directly executed from there, minimizing the amount of slow
>   disk reads and memory copying at runtime.

### In-memory Database

To further speed up any big site you really need to use in-memory database like [Redis](http://redis.io)(I like this) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org). All big sites use one of these. For example Facebook, Twitter could not run without Memcached(Redis would also work but they went with Memcached). This will also really speed up your website.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no caching is involved, serving static files will always be faster than serving dynamic pages. **However**, no matter what type of site you run, you should always be caching, which it be through your webserver, your framework, or through a tool such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

In the end, you should make your decision based not on how fast the site will be, but rather on which choice will make for the most maintainable system in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Even if static pages are going to be *slightly* faster than loading every page from the database, with projects such as these you have to take into consideration numerous other factors. It may be appealing to optimize for performance only, but you do not want to be the one to explain to your users why they need to spend 10 minutes in creating a new quiz because "the database runs more efficiently".

What you need to focus on is usage. If you're the only one who's going to maintain it, sure, static pages might not be bad. But if you're going to hand off the page to non-technical users or if the pages are going to need frequent changing, well, that's why dynamic pages with an administration interface were made for.

If this is a general-use application, I'd "optimize for users" rather than performance. Sure, the latter might take slight hits, but in the end, do not build something you do not want to maintain. Fast changing, multi-user applications - use administration backends.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends your your context, If your data change rate is more then it is recommended dynamic web site that loading pages from database, But If you want to build it fast then obviously static is preferred !