# Replace string in gzip file

Tags: php, caching, gzip

I plan to gzip and cache html pages in the database. Few parts of the cached page need to be replaced with fresh data when it is served back to user.

Is there away to replace string directly in the gzipped pages without ungzipping them? I am using php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there away to replace string directly in the gzipped pages without ungzipping them?

Simple question, simple answer: No it's not.

It's because to modify the original data you need to un-gzip the compressed data first, then modify the uncompressed data and then gzip the whole data again. Gzip always compresses a whole chunk of data, so unless you don't change the whole chunk, you need to uncompress, change and recompress.

Comment: I want to upvote your answer but your reputation is over 9000. 9999 is too cool to change ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking to embed some strings in the html file that act as markers that the gzip will not be able to compress.

Comment: @user215097: I don't know what you would like to do, maybe this question is informative for you as well: [Which is faster: MySQL/PHP or serving straight from static files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869210/which-is-faster-mysql-php-or-serving-straight-from-static-files)

Comment: Thanks Hakre. The question did help. I was thinking if I can add some strings in the html that gzip will ignore or something like this so I can manipulate some parts of the gzip file without decompressing it.